# Is it possible to develop an app using the remove.bg API in Flutter?

Tags: python, flutter, api, dart, remove.bg

- **I got an API called [remove.bg](https://www.remove.bg/api)** . I want to use this API   ( provided in python language )   in my Flutter App. Is it even possible?
- This API uses for removing image background.
- What are the steps/ research I need to do to get this thing working?
- Do lots of Googling, but ends up with nothing.

Really Appreciate your help!!!

- OR can I use [this link](https://www.unscreen.com/upload) and able to upload and get the output in my app?

for example, I open the APP, and it will show two-button -> Upload image  & download image.

when user clicks the **Upload** button it will redirect to [this link](https://www.unscreen.com/upload) and after processing done in the website, the output we can able to download in our app.

Comment: Did you done this project ?

Comment: No ..not in flutter...But I did make a website where if you put your image it will give you the result.

Comment: please share your website link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible with Flutter's [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package. Assuming it is some form of RESTful API this should give you a starting point:

```
final body = {"image_file": "@/path/to/file.jpg", "size": "auto"};
final headers = {"X-API-Key": INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE};
final response = await http.post('https://api.remove.bg/v1.0/removebg', 
  body: body,
  headers: headers);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // do something with response.body
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to do network requests: Error Code: ${response.statusCode}\nBody: ${response.body}');
    }
```

A good tutorial on http in Flutter is [here](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-make-http-requests-in-flutter-d12e98ee1cef).

---

Note: You may have to do `json.encode(body)` and the same with header and use `json.decode(response.body)` depending on the API.

Hope it helps, and if so please up vote and accept as answer and if not please leave a comment below.

Comment: @Tuhin yes, you may