# Flutter remove background from image

Tags: flutter

How to remove background from an image programmatically in flutter. I want to remove background from this below image .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS6DD.jpg)

Comment: refer here:https://gist.github.com/plateaukao/ebb5e7169dd89cc52bda338762d4997e

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Remove Bg API.

official website [Remove bg](https://www.remove.bg/)

For More Information
[Remove API](https://www.remove.bg/api#remove-background)

Comment: Hi , Thankyou for your response.
Remove BG API available only native android(JAVA) and Ios(Swift). I need to using Flutter Project.

Comment: This is available using http package. And they provide rest API that's why we can use in flutter. Review this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60626619/is-it-possible-to-develop-an-app-using-the-remove-bg-api-in-flutter.

Comment: removebg API response get only image . how to set this image in my flutter project.

Comment: @PrajapatiAmit Are you time traveler?

Answer (score -1):

pass your image path to this code:
**assets/imagepath.jpg** : rename this with your path,

[https://www.remove.bg/dashboard#api-key[][1]](https://www.remove.bg/dashboard#api-key%5B%5D%5B1%5D)
open this link and get the api key and copy,

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ApiClient {
  Future<Uint8List> removeBgApi(String imagePath) async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse("https://api.remove.bg/v1.0/removebg"));
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("image_file", imagePath));
    request.headers.addAll({"X-API-Key": " replace with your api key "});
    final response = await request.send();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      http.Response imgRes = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
      return imgRes.bodyBytes;
    } else {
      throw Exception("Error occurred with response ${response.statusCode}");
    }
  }
}



ApiClient().removeBgApi('assets/imagepath.jpg');
```

Answer (score -2):

Using http package, you can access remove.bg rest api & get removed background image.

To remove.bg rest api, you can pass/input image using multipart request & from the response, you can get streamed response using `http.Response.fromStream()` to get removed background image. Below code snippet for the reference,

```
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", remove_bg_api_uri);
var streamedResponse = await request.send()
var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
```

For know more details on how to remove image background using remove.bg api, refer this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CdcTEepfa0).

Comment: It's way too expensive.